# How to index so that text search and sort use the index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoengine

I have a mongoengine document that needs to have a text field search then be sorted. I managed to create the text index, but the sorting operation is comming by very slow. I need a suggestion how to fully index my query:

```
class MyDoc(Document):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'my_doc',
        'index_background': True,
        'indexes': [
            '-sort_field',
            {
                'fields': ['$text_field'],
                'default_language': 'portuguese',
            }
        ],
    }
    text_field = StringField()
    sort_field = DateTimeField()

MyDoc.objects.search_text('some text').sort(['-sort_field'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a text index with another index for the sort. You can have a compound index like `{ "field" : 1, "t" : "text" }` and use the index for equality matches on `field` and text searches, but otherwise text indexes don't work as part of a compound index. Why do you want to do a text search and then sort on another field? It's a slightly unusual use case. It should be fine for returning small numbers of documents, like for returning a page of matching results sorted by date.

Comment: Actually, i need to find documents that match a certain criteria, than show documents that "look more interesting" first. That's why I need to search then sort. Not that unusual. Any eshop need something like that. Can't afford a bulkier solution for now (solr, example).

Comment: MongoDB (as of 3.0 anyway) doesn't have support for the kind of text search + sort you want - you need a real full text search engine to do this right.

Comment: @wdberkeley “ It should be fine for returning small numbers of documents, like for returning a page of matching results sorted by date. ” … not really. When you sort by date, if you have enough data, MongoDB text search fails with `Executor error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33637723 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes`.