# How to both search text then sort the results by another field in MongoDB efficiently?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, query-optimization

So let's say I have the collection `posts` in the format:

```
_id
user
title
body
tags
likes
shares
date
```

I have a text index on `title, body, tags`, then just regular indexes on all the other fields.

What I want to achieve is for the user to be able to search the text fields and have the results sorted by either `likes`, `shares` or `date` (`likes` being the *number of likes*...and `shares` being the *number of shares*, it was possibly ambiguous)

Now, currently, find and sort are very fast on any field - surprisingly, the text fields can even be queried faster than the numeric fields - with something like `db.posts.find({$text: {$search: "computer technology"}}).limit(20)` returning in 0ms. Likewise, if I want to sort based on the likes field with `db.posts.find().sort({likes: 1}).limit(20)`, it will also return in 0ms.

The problem is, however, that if I want a query that **both finds and sorts** on these fields `db.posts.find({$text: {$search: "computer technology"}}).sort({likes: 1}).limit(20)`, then the query takes 8-9s to complete.

With this in mind, I was curious to see if adding a compound index like `db.posts.createIndex({likes: 1, title: "text", body: "text",g: "text", tags: "text"},{name: "ltbt"})`. Of course I realised this would be inefficient from a storage point of view, but I received the error message `only one text index per collection allowed, found existing text index 'tbt'` anyway, which I kind of expected might be the case. Likewise, this approach wouldn't really be viable...since even if you could have multiple text indexes, you'd need the compound index of the text fields with each of the numeric fields you'd want to search by.

So I'm just curious if I have missed something really obvious here or, if not, is there at least some way to improve performance?

Comment: See this post for some useful comments: [How to index so that text search and sort use the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072485/how-to-index-so-that-text-search-and-sort-use-the-index). And this: [Sort and Non-prefix Subset of an Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index).

Comment: https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2020/05/16/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes-the-equality-sort-range-esr-rule/

Comment: @prasad_ thanks for the links. Unfortunately the Mongo site isn't working for me now (I think maybe it's an issue with my browser), but I've saved the link for tomorrow. As for text, it seems like maybe it's hard to order it by relevance...since I tried using the $meta function with the text score, but on 10 million documents, that took something like 40 seconds to sort those matches, then return 20. Do you know if it would be possible to expect text search + sorting to return quickly on a collection of 10 million docs - or would something like a distributed cluster etc be needed?

Comment: @D.SM thanks man. Actually, when I submitted the post, I realised that it would probably be better for a compound index to go {textFields, otherFieldToSortBy} rather than the other way around...considering the text portion of the search would presumably be more restrictive. The thing is though, even if I want to sort based on 3 fields - likes, shares & date, it seems that you can only have 1 text index in MongoDB anyway...whereas as far as I know, the only way I could do it is by having the following 3 indexes on {textFields, likes}, {textFields, shares}, {textFields, date}...

Comment: I dont think a compound index like { textIndex, otherFiled } will work for the sort on the otherField after the textSearch filter (the  sort will not use the index).

Comment: Text indexes are special because they are sparse.